# In json schema, how to chain definitions?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to build a json schema with "chained" definition.

For the given schema :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "id": "http://toto/filter-schema#",
  "title": "filter schema definition",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "filter data",
  "definitions": {
    "timeFilters": {
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "since": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "date-time",
              "description": "sends only items that have been modified AFTER this"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "required": [
            "since"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "from": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "date-time",
              "description": "return only data that have a validity date AFTER this"
            },
            "to": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "date-time",
              "description": "return only data that have a validity date BEFORE this"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "required": [
            "from",
            "to"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "objectFilters": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "objectFilters": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "the array of object filter",
          "minItems": 1,
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "properties": {
                "targetClass": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "description": "the target class"
                },
                "targetAttribute": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "description": "the target attribute"
                },
                "test": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "description": "the test on the attribute value"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/timeFilters",
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/objectFilters",
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

this schema is validating

```
{
  "since": "2016-02-17T01:02:03.1Z"
}
```

and

```
{
  "from": "2016-02-17T01:02:03.1Z",
  "to": "2016-02-17T01:02:03.1Z",
}
```

and

```
{
  "objectFilters": [
    {
      "targetClass": "test",
      "targetAttribute": "test",
      "test": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

and even

```
{}
```

but not

```
{
  "since": "2016-02-17T01:02:03.1Z",
  "objectFilters": [
    {
      "targetClass": "test",
      "targetAttribute": "test",
      "test": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can make it validating the last json ?

I have tried to add a new definition to the "anyOf", something like this :

```
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/timeFilters",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/objectFilters",
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
```

but it does not work.

I use the draft v4.

EDIT : 
Also tried

```
{
  "$ref": "#/definitions/timeFilters",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/objectFilters",
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```

not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `additionalProperties` can get confusing when combining schemas.  I suggest a different approach.  It's easier to declare all your properties upfront and then declare the required properties constraints separately.

The `dependencies` keyword works well in this case.

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor70

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "id": "http://toto/filter-schema#",
  "title": "filter schema definition",
  "description": "filter data",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "since": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time",
      "description": "sends only items that have been modified AFTER this"
    },
    "from": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time",
      "description": "return only data that have a validity date AFTER this"
    },
    "to": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time",
      "description": "return only data that have a validity date BEFORE this"
    },
    "objectFilters": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "the array of object filter",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "targetClass": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "the target class"
            },
            "targetAttribute": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "the target attribute"
            },
            "test": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "the test on the attribute value"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "since": {
      "not": { "required": ["from"] }
    },
    "from": ["to"],
    "to": ["from"]
  }
}
```